# AJAX return html page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, xmlhttprequest

I've setup a simple python REST server:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
    {
        'id': 0,
        'text': u'working!', 
    }
]

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify({'data': data})

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        debug=True,
        host=app.config.get("HOST", "192.168.1.101"),
        port=app.config.get("PORT", 5000)
        )
```

Then I'm doing a simple `XMLHttpRequest` to retreive data:

```
doRequest('http://192.168.1.101:5000/data', function(err, response) { 
        if (err) {
            return "error";

        } else {
            console.log(response);
        } 
    });
}

function doRequest(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create a new request here

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true); // for async
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {     
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                // pass the response to the callback function
                callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else {
                // pass the error to the callback function
                callback(xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

**Problem**
The result is a bit weird. If I visit the webpage in incognito mode it works fine, I get a JSON file as response, as expected. If I open it in normal browser mode I get a whole HTML page as response. Why is this happening?

Comment: `I get a whole HTML page as response` - which page do you get?

Comment: @JaromandaX the page I'm making the request from

Comment: What HTTP header do you send/get for each case?